# Linux command in Go server for continuous integration

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, environment-variables, go-cd

I am using Go server for continuous integration of our code. For my environment-deploy-template, I wish to set certain environment variables on the stage and then echo those in the property files for the application. What would be the Linux command that I could give in my job to do so?

For example, it could be some thing like :

```
echo "propName=#{env variable}\n">>prop files location
```

Could someone please confirm this?

Comment: Are you talking about the continuous delivery product http://www.go.cd/ rather than the programming language? I've modified your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to get go.cd env variable is `${ENV_VAR}` and a full command is:

```
echo propName=${ENV_VAR} >> props.txt
```

More details on environment variables: [Using Environment Variables in Go](http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/faq/dev_use_current_revision_in_build.html)